# Do items in houses respawn?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

So I've read up on plenty of posts regarding the respawning of things in the game. Which then I concluded all areas (Main, dungeons, caves, towns, etc) entered at a lower level then 40 are pointless to clear out on a return visit as per the in game week respawn period of all chest, hidden items, carts, corpses, reagents, and so forth (By this I mean you can not clear out all areas for the mere satisfaction of 101% completion, and since the areas level lock upon entry to what your level was no need for going in for low level items). However with the exception of houses the items may be of low level however the question is do these things respawn? If so, are books, letters, keys omitted from this or are only certain books, and letters omitted such as skill books or quest related items?

Example: By this method could one, in retrospect, harvest bookshelves to amass a collection of all Amalur literature? Or could one simply clear out all houses for just a little sanctification of perfection?

P.S. Disregarding the inventory/stash limitations, as this is easily circumvented via killing the vendors to create duplicates of items, such as backpacks, which translates to infinite space.

Answer (score 1):

Important and unique items won't respawn. So skill books, keys and the like wont be found a second time.

You can find up to blue-level randomly in the same area when containers respawn. I know that only tribute will respawn in player housing, but I haven't really payed attention to respawning in other houses. It seems to be on a different timer than the rest of the area.

Futhermore house respawn may be delayed it you don't loot the whole house.

Comment: Thank you for the response, actually regarding keys I have found a duplicate in the house of ballads although I think this was simply due to a technicality. I had recently received a chance to test if house items respawn and the answer seems to be no beyond regents found in doors.

Based on this and your response the following can be gathered:

There is a set list of literature, keys, peasant/farmer clothing (with perhaps the exception of killing citizens? [Have not tested to see if they do drop such items and have only found torn, or ragged clothing in the wild)]),  Infrequent (Green), ...

Comment: Rare (Blue), Unique (Purple), Set Items (Gold) in the game that can be obtained. And perhaps a few other oddities such as ceremonial daggers, or bones may even have a set number.

With this in mind regarding the items a follow up questions seems prevalent to ask, blacksmithing. If there is in fact a set list of items in Green, Blue, Purple, and Gold classes is there also a set list of components and materials that can only be obtained via salvaging these items? (Exclusive materials and or components that can only be obtained via salvaging this equipment)

Comment: @AmalurAddict I have gotten duplicate purple and golds, but I do not believe from the same source.

Comment: Alright cool, thanks for the info. Looks like the only thing exclusive to collect is books, keys, possibly peasant/farmer clothing, and oddities.